# What's the difference between "DELETE TABLE" and "DELETE FROM" in SQL Developer?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am using SQL Dev to manage Oracle DB and I just found out that it suggests a DELETE syntax like that :

```
DELETE TABLE(SELECT h.people FROM hr_info h
   WHERE h.department_id = 280) p
   WHERE p.salary > 1700
```

I don't find anything on Google with "delete table" syntax, as usually the syntax is "delete from".

What's the difference with this veresion ?

```
DELETE FROM hr_info h
   WHERE h.department_id = 280
   AND h.salary > 1700
```

I mean, the first one creates a temporary table containing people from dep_id = 280 then delete all salary > 1700.

But the standard one seems faster as it directly deletes all dep_ip = 200 and salary > 1700. SO it does that in a single step while the other in two steps.

And I guess it gives the same result.

Or am I missing something ?

Thanks.

Comment: "first one creates a temporary table containing people" is wrong. The first query is not creating a temporary table, the table collection expression `TABLE()` is accessing a table that is nested within the rows of the `people` column of the `hr_info` table and then the outer `DELETE` is deleting rows from the nested table (and not the `hr_info` table).

Comment: There is some description in [Oracle docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/appdev.101/b10807/13_elems014.htm) under "TABLE (subquery2)"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are doing different things, because they operate on different data types.

In the second query:

```
DELETE FROM hr_info h
   WHERE h.department_id = 280
   AND h.salary > 1700
```

the `salary` column is a scalar data type, presumably of number. The deletion removes the matching rows from the `hr_info` table, as you'd expect.

But the first query:

```
DELETE TABLE(SELECT h.people FROM hr_info h
   WHERE h.department_id = 280) p
   WHERE p.salary > 1700
```

would error if that was the case, with 'ORA-22905: cannot access rows from a non-nested table type'.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/scWFqlay)

Which means for that query to work, the `people` column must be nested table of an object type, which has fields including `salary`. (There is also a clue in that the table subquery doesn't project a `salary` column.) For example, it could have been defined as something like:

```
create type t_person as object (person_id number, name varchar2(30), salary number)
/

create type t_people as table of t_person
/

create table hr_info (department_id number, people t_people)
nested table people store as tab_people
```

The `TABLE()` clause is then finding the `hr_info` row for department 280 and presenting the nested table from the people column in that row, which is projected as `p`. This is briefly described [in the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/adobj/operations-on-collection-data-types.html#GUID-67C2AA68-EBD2-4BBF-823A-F1D5FE536314). The deletion then operates on that nested table, and deletes rows from that with matching salaries; [from the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/adobj/operations-on-collection-data-types.html#GUID-C7FC0A7A-F958-4790-8711-4983350BEDD4):

> For piecewise operations on nested table columns, use the TABLE expression.
>
> The TABLE expression uses a subquery to extract the nested table, so that the INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE statement applies to the nested table rather than the top-level table.

That deletion is then removing rows from that nested table, *not* from the `hr_info` table. There is still a single row for department 280, but its nested `people` table may now have fewer rows than it did before the delete.

And with this table definition the second query would now fail, with 'ORA-00904: "H"."SALARY": invalid identifier'.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/cfmprQUi)

---

As an aside really, the `FROM` keyword [is optional](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/DELETE.html); so `DELETE hr_info ...` and `DELETE FROM TABLE(...)...` are also both valid. That documentation also refers to deleting from a nested table collection.

Comment: Yes I know how it would process the full query. My question was why using that kind of thing? Because if I understand well the delete won't modify the real table? But as the data is only available the time of the delete you cannot use that anywhere else? If you have real example of this kind of use be my guess.

Comment: No, your description of what's happening is wrong - "I guess it gives the same result" is not correct. They are not equivalent, one applies to nested tables, the other does not. The syntax in your first query does modify the real table/data too - it's just modifying the (real) nested table within the table. The fiddle shows a different result querying the table before and after the delete.